# Type casting and Bit Manipulation Mystery

Tags: c, casting, bit-manipulation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;
typedef short               int16_t;
typedef unsigned short      uint16_t;
typedef int                 int32_t;
typedef unsigned int        uint32_t;
int main(){
    uint8_t ball; 
    uint8_t fool;
    ball=((unsigned char)13);
    fool=((unsigned char)14);
    uint16_t combined_value1=((uint16_t)ball)<<12+((uint16_t)fool)<<8; // WRONG ONE
    uint16_t combined_value2=((uint16_t)ball<<12)+((uint16_t)fool<<8);
    printf("%hu\n",(uint16_t)combined_value1);
    printf("%hu\n",(uint16_t)combined_value2);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the value of "combined_value1" wrong? Here ball and fool take value from 0 to 15 and I am trying to concatenate combined_value as { ball[4 bits] : fool[4 bits] : [8 zero bits] }.

Comment: You do know your typedefs are possibly conflicting with `stdint.h`, right? In fact, the whole point of the header eliminate typedefs like the ones you added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than `<<`, so

```
((uint16_t)ball)<<12+((uint16_t)fool)<<8;
```

is evaluated as

```
((uint16_t)ball) << (12+((uint16_t)fool)) << 8;
```

Please note that `(uint16_t)` casting does not make much sense in this context, since after that promotion to `int` takes place. Instead, consider

```
uint16_t combined_value = (uint16_t)((ball<<12) + (fool<<8));
```

There are several other redundant castings too. And as **@StoryTeller** suggested, it would be better to include `stdint.h`.

Comment: A link to the [**C Operator Precedence Table**](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) may give a bit more information to help not only with `+` and `<<`, but with all operators in the future.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, I added a link to the post too.

Comment: It's a good answer, but I always try to give the questioner direction to the reference that allow him to solve the problem on his own the next time he encounters it. (the old "Give a man a fish, feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, feed him for life... analogy). Thanks for the addition.